# Circumference in 2D curved space

Tags: homework-and-exercises, differential-geometry

If we consider the metric to be $ds^2 = \frac{dr^2}{1-kr^2} + r^2 d\phi^2$ and want to compute the length $L$ of a path we know that:
$$L = \int_{path}ds$$
With the path defined by $\{r=r_1, 0 <\phi < 2\pi\}$.

My question is how do I compute this thing correctly?

My first thought was to set $dr=0$, as long $r=r_1$ which is a constant, but this will return the Euclidean circle circumference $L=2\pi r_1$.

It's a very basic question, but I didn't really get it with all lectures/books that I read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The point here is that $r$ is just an arbitrary coordinate, i.e. a number which marks the points along a line which has not necessarily anything to do with the radius.
For the radius in this metric is not $r$, but

$$R = \int_0^{r_1} \frac{dr}{\sqrt{1-kr^2}}$$

For simplicity we will assume positive curvature $k=+1$, then we get (due to the proposed metric now there is dimension problem that will be, however, neglected as it does not matter in this demonstration)

$$R =   \int_0^{r_1} \frac{dr}{\sqrt{1-r^2}}  = arsin(r_1) $$

Therefore the ratio between circumference and radius is not $2\pi$, but

$$\frac{U}{R} = 2\pi \frac{r_1}{arcsin(r_1)} \geq 2\pi$$

For small $r_1\ll 1$ it is nevertheless still

$$\frac{U}{R} = 2\pi \frac{r_1}{r_1} = 2\pi $$

Comment: So, the $r^2$ inside the metric for the $d\phi^2$ term represent the distance between the origin and the point $(r_1,0)$ (or whatever point $(r_1,\phi)$ ) and as long the $dr^2$ term of the metric is not $1$ we can't say that distant is equal to $r_1$. If it's that, thank you for your help. I wouldn't imagine this in that way.

Comment: As I said $r$ is marker for marking points monotonously along a line. It has nothing to do with a distance. Distances is obtained by integrating $ds$ along a path given by the integration borders. In particular one could make a coordinate transformation, then the metric would be different, but the distances don't change by the coordinate transformation, but there would be no $r$ anymore, there would be different coordinate called $z=z(r,...)$ for instance.

Comment: This is incorrect, the question is about the length of a circle, not a radial path. $2\pi r$ is the correct answer.

Comment: @Javier: The post already gives the answer of length of circle in terms of the coordinate $r$, however, to put it in the context, it has to be compared to the radius of the circular path, but the radius of the circular path is different from the coordinate value of $r$.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I had misunderstood your answer. Unfortunately after 1 hour the system doesn't let me remove the downvote. I still feel like it could be phrased better, however.